# How can I get exclusive access to all executors on a Jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to maximize my agent usage, and I've got various types of agents and various needs for the jobs.

We have two types of agents:

- Virtual machines, which have only one executor
- Physical machines, which have five executors

We have three general types of jobs:

- Automated user interface tests that interact with the desktop
- Product performance (timing) tests
- Functional regression tests

Here are the criteria:

- The performance tests must have exclusive access to the physical agents
- The UI tests are timing-sensitive, so they should also have exclusive access to any agent it runs on
- The functional regression tests can be run anywhere, on any number of executors

I can make use of the "Job Weight" plugin, which causes a particular build of a job to take up a specific number of nodes. I can also make use of the "Throttle Concurrent Builds" plugin, which can limit the number of concurrently running builds per node. However, I can't find a combination that works.

#### Example 1:

- UI tests throttled to one build per agent
- Performance tests given a job weight of five

#### Problem 1:

- Functional tests can run on the same agent as a UI test.

#### Example 2:

- UI tests and functional tests throttled to one build per agent (sharing a throttle category)
- Performance tests given a weight of five

#### Problem 2:

- Functional tests are now limited to one executor per agent, therefore not maximizing the physical agents

#### Example 3:

- Set Performance and UI tests to job weight of five

#### Problem 3:

- UI tests will no longer use the virtual machine agents.

If the "Job Weight" plugin had a "Max" setting (which would just use all of the executors on the agent), that would make this problem go away. I could then set the UI and Performance tests to have a job weight of "Max" and be done with it.

Any suggestions on how to get these criteria to fit together with the current limitations of Jenkins and its plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is what we did. All agents were given five executors each.

The job weights were changed around a bit:

- Functional tests given a weight of one
- Performance tests given a weight of five
- UI tests given a weight of five

We then used the throttle plugin and created two categories that throttle according to labels:

- 1_per_any_agent limits any jobs associated with that category to run only one job on the agent at a time.
- 1_per_vm_agent limits any jobs associated with that category to run only one job on a VM agent at a time, but isn't limited for physical agents.

We applied the 1_per_any_agent throttle category to the performance and UI tests and applied the 1_per_vm_agent throttle category to the functional tests.

Now, functional tests can have five builds running simultaneously on physical agents, but are limited to only one on virtual agents. They will not run when performance or UI tests are running because those jobs require a weight of five.